# Total price increases whenever item is removed from cart instead of minus in REACT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building an online store with react using context api...Now, I'm facing a particular issue with total price in cart.

THE PROBLEM: I was successful getting the total price of items in cart using reduce but if I remove an item from cart, the total price increases instead of decreasing.

I made a new state named totalPrice then in useEffect, I setTotalPrice to (productsPrice.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))
productsPrice is an array that consist of all the prices of products added to cart

Any help??

```
 useEffect(() => {
      //Add new products in cart price to productPrice state array
      cartProducts.map((prod) => {
        return setProductPrice([...productPrice, prod.price]);
      });

      //Calculate all price in product price array and set the total price to TotalProductPrice state
      function getPrice() {
        const total = productPrice.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
        setTotalProductPrice(total);
      }
      getPrice();
    }, [cartProducts]);
```

Comment: Please insert related code in to question. Seems like you forgot to add `productPrice` as a dependency for your `useEffect` hook.

Comment: Can you post the code, please? It's impossible to help you otherwise.

Comment: code has been added

Comment: Where do you remove the products? Right now you just add more prices to the productPrice state array from what I can see, never deleting anything.

Comment: I have a function for removing product in my context

Answer (score 0):

I do not think I understand your problem well, but why you do not use a direct action in the following store when clicking on deletion you have the index of the product, just browse the table, and delete the article and the price * quantity.
If not please explain your problem better

Comment: I have an array that consist of products price in cart...then i create a new state to store the total price using the array that have the product price in cart with .reduce()

Comment: try with the method in my other comment instead of reduce

Answer (score 0):

when adding an article to card, you add with an action in card state, and  the price * quantity in the state of total, after you delete an article you delete it in card, then you take the total state-> total = total - item price * quantity